# Core data design setup sending user data and receiving server data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to figure out how to design a core-data setup.

I have one NSManagedObjectContext that runs in the main thread which is getting updated by another background thread(it has its own context) updating the main context by using the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification callback: This part of the system works fine.

My problem is when trying to save user data and how to send an immediately request to the web server for saving this data, while still adding it to the main context.
The entity object is important because the request for saving the user data on the server is generated by looking at its attributes. And this entity object should be correctly updated if it has successfully updated the data on the web-server (from the background context to the main context).

So for example if i would create a new NSEntityDescription linked to the main context, do i listen to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and then create a background thread for which i would create a new context and send the entity object id. This would then update the main context and setting the object entity to sent?

Comment: Please _show_ rather than _describe_ your code. Thank you.

Comment: My question is more a design setup - what code do i show for that?

Answer (score 0):

Make the change to your managedObjects in your main thread's mananagedObjectContext (but don't save your moc), send off a request to the server to make the change (using something like NSURLConnection -sendAsynchronous request), in your completion handler on success fire off your own NSNotification to alert your controller it's now safe to save the moc. If it fails, you could alert the user, use core data's undo, or something along those lines.

Comment: The problem is that the system should automatically read the entity object(attributes) and dynamically send its content to the web server (so that it works with different entities). Meaning i would like to read the object entity from a background thread.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you are on the right track conceptually with core data. NSEntityDescription is used to build your core data data model in code. Most people use the data modeling tool in xcode instead. The model itself is not something you modify at runtime, generally, as it needs to be "complete" before your persistentStoreCoordinator is setup. And once your app is out there, modifying the model requires a data migration to the new model.